# Prove that if $A \setminus B ⊆ C ∩ D$ and $x \in A$ and $x \not \in D$ then $x \in B$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Suppose $A \setminus B ⊆ C ∩ D$ and $x \in A$. Prove that if $x \not
> \in D$ then $x \in B$.

We can rewrite $A \setminus B ⊆ C ∩ D$ using logical connectives as follows:
$(x \in A \land x \not \in B) \implies  (x \in C \land x \in D)$

It can be seen that if $x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$ then x **must** be in $D$.

Given that $x \not \in D$. In this case,  either $x \not  \in A$ or $x \in B$.

Given that $x \in A$. Therefore, $x \in B$.

---

Apparently, more complete way to describe statement $A \setminus B ⊆ C ∩ D$ would be 
$\forall x \big((x \in A \land x \not \in B) \implies  (x \in C \land x \in D)\big)$

Is it OK to omit quantifier ($\forall$) like I did?
And in general, is the proof above correct? Any suggestions for improvement will be welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is correct, there's no need to improve anything unless you want to be very formal. You can omit the quantifier $\forall$, because if something is true for all $x$, then it's particularily true for the one $x$ that you're given.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \notin D$ then $x \notin C \cap D$, so $x \notin A\setminus B$ by the given inclusion. But we already know $x \in A$ so $x \notin B$ *would* make it an element of $A \setminus B$ which it is not, so $x \in B$ must hold.